# Integral of determinant of Jacobian of a $C^{1}$ application.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f \in C^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n}; \mathbb{R}^{n})$, suppose that exists $r>0$ such that $f(x)=0$ if $|x|>r$. Prove that exists $k>0$ such that

$\int_{\overline{B_{k}(0)}} det Jf(x) dx=0$.

My work:

Let$g:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as  $g(t)=\int_{\overline{B_{t}(0)}} det Jf(x) dx$. I want to prove that $g$ is a continuous function e to prove that there $p,q\in (0,\infty)$ such that $g(p)<0<g(q)$ then the intermediate value theorem ensures that there exists the number $k>0$ s.t $g(k)=0$. I'm in the right way?

Comment: Not even close :(